# django-import-export update profile if email exists

Tags: django, django-import-export

I have this `unique field` on my `Profile model`:

```
email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, unique=True)
```

and I have this `ProfileResource`:

```
class ProfileResource(resources.ModelResource):

    # associated_issuer = fields.Field(attribute='add_associated_issuer', widget=ManyToManyWidget(Issuer, field='name'), column_name='Associated Issuer')
    email = fields.Field(attribute='email', 
        widget=CharWidget(), 
        column_name='email')

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        clean_model_instances = True
        import_id_fields = ('id', 'email')

    def before_import_row(self, row, row_number=None, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.email = row["email"] 
        except Exception as e:
            self.email = ""

        try:
            if row["id"] == '':
                row["id"] = None
                self.id = row["id"] 
        except Exception as e:
            self.id = None

        try:
           self.firstname = row["firstname"] 
        except Exception as e:
            self.firstname = ""

        try:
           self.lastname = row["lastname"]
        except Exception as e:
            self.lastname = ""
```

Now when I try to do an import from a file, I receive this error:

[image]

I need to be able to do an `update_or_create` method, but where do I add that code? I tried doing it on an `after_import_instance` but it did not work.

I also tried on `import_row` like this:

```
def import_row(self, row, instance_loader, using_transactions=True, dry_run=False, **kwargs):
    try:
        Profile.objects.update_or_create(email=self.email)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e, file=sys.stderr)
```

but it produced this error:

```
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'import_type'
```

Any insights on a fix would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you have this line on your `ProfileResource`

> import_id_fields = ('id', 'email')

This means that the import will look at each row in your import file, and attempt to load any `Profile` instances which match both `id` and `email`.

Therefore if you only need to update `email`, then simply remove this from the list of `import_id_fields`.  By doing that, the logic will uniquely identify instances based solely on `id`, and then new records will be created if they don't exist, and any existing records will be updated (which will include updating the email address).

This is how `import-export` is supposed to work and no further logic is required.

If `email` is the "unique field" which matches your existing instances, then this should be the only field in `import_id_fields`.  There cannot be two `Profile` instances with the same email, because `unique=True`, therefore you can use `email` as the `import_id_field`.  However it will not be possible to update the `Profile` email using `import-export` (although you could introduce a field called `new_email` and have logic to update the `Profile` that way, but that is a separate topic).

I don't know why you are seeing the 'email already exists' error - possibly something else is going on, and it could be the logic in `before_import_row()` which is causing the problem, probably due to the fact that a row is being created with empty string as the email.

btw - you shouldn't need any of the logic in `before_import_row()` - `import-export` should handle this for you, and by overriding you might be introducing further bugs.

The best advice for using `import-export` is to set breakpoints in your IDE, and then step through during an import and you can see exactly what is happening.  This will save you a lot of time in the long run.

In summary, use **either** `id` or `email` in `import_id_fields` and it should work.

Comment: the 'email already exists' error is only present if the id field is blank. if the value for the id is present, it updates fine. I suppose it gives out that error because it does a create rather than an update.

Comment: correct - it will be trying to create a new row with the given email address - if it already exists you will see the error.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to change

```
import_id_fields = ('id', 'email')
```

by

```
import_id_fields = ('email',)
```

When you try to import row with empty ID, it will always be perceived as new row. So it does a create rather than an update in this case. But when you leave only `email` in your `import_id_fields`, it obviously will do an update instead of create.

Have you already tried this?

Answer (score -1):

```py
#try this 

email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, unique=True, null=True)

        try:
            self.email = row["email"] 
        except Exception as e:
            self.email = None
```

`unique=True` also block duplicated "", but null is not blocked.