# Django-import-export update_or_create with UniqueConstraint

Tags: django, django-import-export

I have this `Profile model` together with a `constraint` similar to a `unique_together`:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    #Personal Information
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
    investor_type = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=investor_type_choices)

    class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['email', 'investor_type'], name='email and investor_type')
    ]
```

I want to implement a function `update_or_create` on the `Profile` which uses the `email` and `investor_type` as the argument for searching for the `object`.

I tried adding this to my `ProfileResource`:

```
def before_import_row(self, row, row_number=None, **kwargs):
    try:
        self.email = row["email"]
    except Exception as e:
        self.email = None

    try:
       self.investor_type = row["investor_type"] 
    except Exception as e:
        self.investor_type = None

def after_import_instance(self, instance, new, row_number=None, **kwargs):
    try:
        # print(self.isEmailValid(self.email), file=sys.stderr)
        if self.email and self.investor_type:
            profile, created = Profile.objects.update_or_create(
                email=self.email, 
                investor_type=self.investor_type,
                defaults={
                    'firstname': 'helloo',
                    'lastname': 'wooorld',
                })

    except Exception as e:
        print(e, file=sys.stderr)
```

but adding a non-existing `Profile object`:

[image]

[image]

through `django-import-export`:

[image]

is already giving out an error, `Profile with this Email and Investor type already exists` despite it not existing in the first place.

[image]

Comment: Can you use 'email' and 'type' as 'import_id_fields'?  check the docs and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70121673/39296)

Comment: yeah, this worked! I forgot about the import_id_fields. Thank you!